# Software Testing - Selenium/TestNG - Use of arrays and loops + objects?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automated-tests, testng

So I am new to programming + Selenium + testNG - Self taught so far. I've been a manual tester for over a year now writing test plans etc, however, getting into automation. My question is i've created some automated tests that will login with different user details using the data provider by creating an object and returning there details. I have also been passing in parameters from an Excel sheet using the Apache POI function.

So far i've been using a lot of finding the elements + clicking on them + passing in parameters values or object values. How much more complex does software automation get? I've never used loops yet and the only array i've used is the excel utils for passing in the parameters from an excel?

```
 Object[][] testObjArray = ExcelUtils.getTableArray("C://Selenium-java-maven//workSpace//Practice-test//src//testData//TestData.xlsx", "Sheet1");

       return (testObjArray);
```

What am saying is apart from testing the functionality of a website/app from the front end what else is selenium used for + other frameworks?

I am not the most confident programmer I managed to get a 1st at university, however, this type of programming seems more lightweight compared with say a software developer is this correct?

Does anyone know were I could view some industry standard selenium tests so I can compare it to what i've done so far? Surely these tests get more complex?

Comment: Search selenium on github

Comment: There is no definition of standard test and thus you don't need to compare with others, just write tests and see if it helps you in testing.